# Let $a$ and $n$ be integers, such that $a,n>1$ and $n$ is not a perfect square; show that: $a^{\sqrt{n}}$ is a transcendental number.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, exponential-function, transcendental-numbers

Although it is very hard to determine if a number is transcendental, I could appreciate any basic or simple insight or opinion concerning the statement, whether it is true or false.

Regards

Comment: True, a special case of the [Gelfond-Schneider Theorem.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfond%E2%80%93Schneider_theorem)

Comment: Wow! Thanks @AndréNicolas

Comment: You are welcome. One of the famous Hilbert problems, huge literature. Sort of related, Lindemann-Weierstrass.

Answer (score 1):

It is true but not by any known "simple" insight but by a deep result known as the Gelfond theorem.The case  a=n=2 was mentioned in David Hilbert's famous "Problem Set" over a century ago .The best I can do is to suggest some reading. If anyone wants to type out a complete proof of the Gelfond theorem here they'll probably get flagged.THEOREM  (Gelfond): If $x,y$ are  complex algebraic numbers , $0\ne x \ne1$, and $y$  not a rational real, then any value of $x^y$ is transcendental over the rationals...... For any integer $n$ let $l_n=i(2 \pi n+\arg x)+\ln |x|$ . We have $\exp (l_n)=x$ and we let $\exp (y l_n)$ be "a value of $x^y$".

Comment: Thanks for the extra information, I should've guessed that it was already a known case in mathematics. @user254665

Comment: Hilbert's problem set was a list of questions that he thought were important ones for 20th century mathematicians. Some are still open.